# How to get only store name from below series with store name being index of the series

Tags: python, pandas

how to get 1st store name from below series with store name being the index using iloc attribute

```
purchase_1 = pd.Series({'Name': Surya,
                        'Item Purchased': ' Pen ',
                        'Cost': 22.50})
purchase_2 = pd.Series({'Name': Deepak,
                        'Item Purchased': ' book ',
                        'Cost': 2.50})
purchase_3 = pd.Series({'Name': Mindaguditi,
                        'Item Purchased': ' chocolate ',
                        'Cost': 5.00})
df = pd.DataFrame([purchase_1, purchase_2, purchase_3], index=['Store 1', 'Store 1', 'Store 2'])
df.head()
```

Comment: Do you want `print (df.index[0])` ?

Comment: i want to create a function to return the first store name with return as iloc[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems need [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select first row to `Series` with `name` attribute:

```
print (df.iloc[0])
Cost               22.5
Item Purchased     Pen 
Name              Surya
Name: Store 1, dtype: object

print (df.iloc[0].name)
Store 1
```